# stimulsoft Report Viewer Costumize

Tags: c#, .net, stimulsoft

I am using Stimulsoft Report 2015 Ultimate. I want to hide "Save" and "Open" button is in viewer occasionally, 
i have seen the Stimulsoft Sample "Costume VIew" but it shows report in a form, while i am going to use report viewer itself.
so the methode does not worked for me
by default i am using these lines to generate report:

```
private void btnItemList_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  ItemListReport.Dictionary.Variables.Add("ProjectName", Globals.ProjectName);
  ItemListReport.Dictionary.Variables.Add("ProjectCode", Globals.ProjectCode);
  ItemListReport.Dictionary.Variables.Add("Username", Globals.SajiranClient.Username);
  ItemListReport.Compile();
  ItemListReport.Render();
  ItemListReport.Show();
  ItemListReport.ViewerControl = PreviewControl;  
}
```

also, i was using this to hide those controls, but no success:

```
private void btnItemList_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Stimulsoft.Report.Viewer.StiViewerControl PreviewControl = new Stimulsoft.Report.Viewer.StiViewerControl();
  PreviewControl.ShowOpen = false;
  PreviewControl.ShowSave = false;
  PreviewControl.ShowSendEMail = false;
  PreviewControl.Report = ItemListReport;
  PreviewControl.SaveConfig();
  PreviewControl.Refresh();
  PreviewControl.LoadConfig();

  ItemListReport.Dictionary.Variables.Add("ProjectName", Globals.ProjectName);
  ItemListReport.Dictionary.Variables.Add("ProjectCode", Globals.ProjectCode);
  ItemListReport.Dictionary.Variables.Add("Username", Globals.SajiranClient.Username);

   ItemListReport.Compile();

   ItemListReport.Render();
   ItemListReport.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Stioptions.viewer.windows.showsavebutton=false
```

Comment: Elaborate on the answer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.